# "Cannot get automation extension" error on headless chrome with Selenium (Ubuntu)

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, canopy-web-testing

I've installed latest Google Chrome 57.0.2987.110, on my Ubuntu server (16.04).
I'm using canopy (which is F# wrapper for Selenium).
I put latest chromedriver in the same folder as my binary, version: 2.28.455506 (and I set the correct path to driver).

I'm starting chrome with `--headless` argument, like this:

```
  let chromeOpts = ChromeOptions ()
  chromeOpts.AddArgument "--headless"
  chromeOpts.AddArgument "--disable-gpu"
  chromeOpts.AddArgument "start-maximized"

  start <| ChromeWithOptions chromeOpts
```

As soon as it's starts I get this error:

> [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.InvalidOperationException: unknown error: cannot get automation extension
>   from unknown error: page could not be found: chrome-extension://aapnijgdinlhnhlmodcfapnahmbfebeb/_generated_background_page.html
>     (Session info: content shell=)
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.28.455506 (18f6627e265f442aeec9b6661a49fe819aeeea1f),platform=Linux 4.4.0-64-generic x86_64)
>     at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError (OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.Response errorResponse) [0x000d5] in <2096f357ed27440a8e98c8a8dd645cdd>:0
>     at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute (System.String driverCommandToExecute, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue] parameters) [0x00046] in <2096f357ed27440a8e98c8a8dd645cdd>:0
>     at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.InternalExecute (System.String driverCommandToExecute, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary 2[TKey,TValue] parameters) [0x00000] in <2096f357ed27440a8e98c8a8dd645cdd>:0
>     at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWindow.set_Size (System.Drawing.Size value) [0x00067] in <2096f357ed27440a8e98c8a8dd645cdd>:0
>     at canopy.core.pin (canopy.types+direction direction) [0x0002f] in <58c4b5b9d8107025a7450383b9b5c458>:0
>     at canopy.core.start (canopy.types+BrowserStartMode b) [0x0050c] in <58c4b5b9d8107025a7450383b9b5c458>:0

It's seems that it fails to set window size. 
Is it proper way to launch headless Chrome? I read somewhere that newest version has headless feature.
As I'm using newest version of both Google Chrome and chromedriver I think it shouldn't be a version mismatch.

Also it's working fine on ma local Windows 10 machine with same version of chromedrive (just for windows).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running with command (and without headless argument):

`DISPLAY=:1 xvfb-run mono myapp.exe`

Seems to work. I think this resolves my issue.
I leave it here for others looking for a way tu run headless chrome and having same problem.

This solution comes from: http://coderscoffeehouse.com/tech/2017/01/17/headless-front-end-testing-on-linux-using-fsharp.html

Comment: Please don't forget to come back and mark this as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There's an open Chromium [issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=706008) on this topic. It states:

> Headless mode doesn't currently support extensions, and it's not clear
>   whether we can support them easily -- although we are doing some
>   initial feasibility analysis.

As suggested by @mateuszlewko, the X Virtual Framebuffer (XVFB) can be used as a Linux workaround.